# IIS 10 - http2_protocol_error

Tags: c#, vb.net, iis, http2

I'm facing some weird http2 issue on iis 10.
I got http2_protocol_error in chrome, edge during very long loading of my web apps.
It starts to work after disabling http2 in iis binding settings.

There are 2 super easy steps to replay it in my case:

1. Add sleep or delay of 2 or more minutes to any endpoint.
2. Recompile it, deploy to iis and run this endpoint in chrome or edge.

What can I provide you with to help me solving this issue?

Those times, apps were not meant to work in timely fashion, just click, wait a few minutes for report and go on.

I didn't found so much posts in Internet so I assume that it's my fault.
Apart from that:
https://help.goacoustic.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052067413-Disable-HTTP-2-in-IIS-10

Comment: you sure this is due to https? One REALLY HUGE difference is that in debug.mode, then the timeout settings for the site are ignored. When you deploy to production, build as release, and have debug="false"? Then timeout settings for the webmehtods ARE NOW enforced. So, during debugging you not see them, and this is not the result of https. Unless you saying you test/try above deployed to a produciton server with debug=false, and EVEN when not using https (you use http) you still see the same error (timeout)? so, just keep in mind that during debugging, then the webmethod's timeouts are ignored

Comment: HTTP/2 typically requires the use of TLS (encrypted connections). Make sure your site has TLS enabled and that the TLS setting is correct.
If the problem occurs during a long load, there may be a connection timeout related issue.
I suggest you check the IIS logs and Windows Event Viewer for any error messages or warnings.